# Finding every friday from start date till the end of the year

Tags: c#, datetime

So I'm back with another baffling DateTime question.

In C#, how would I return the (day) for every Friday from a start date (`DateTime.Now`) until the end of the current year?

So for example, today being Friday the 19th, it would return, 26, 2, 9, 16, 23, 30, 7, etc.

Comment: Is the start date a friday or do you need to figure out the first friday also?

Comment: I'd need to figure out the first friday because the day won't always be friday when I'm checking.

Answer (score 9):

Does this work?

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetFridays(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
{
    // step forward to the first friday
    while (startdate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday)
        startdate = startdate.AddDays(1);

    while (startdate < enddate)
    {
        yield return startdate;
        startdate = startdate.AddDays(7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var start = DateTime.Today;
var startDay = ((int) start.DayOfWeek);
var nextFriday = startDay<6 //5 if today is friday and you don't want to count it
                 ? start.AddDays(5 - startDay)   //friday this week
                 : start.AddDays(12 - startDay); //friday next week
var remainingFridays = Enumerable.Range(0,53)
                       .Select(i => nextFriday.AddDays(7 * i))
                       .TakeWhile(d => d.Year == start.Year);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do what you want.

```
IList<int> getFridaysForYearFromPoint(DateTime startDate)
{
    DateTime currentFriday = startDate;
    List<int> results = new List<int>();

    //Find the nearest Friday forward of the start date
    while(currentFriday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday)
    {
        currentFriday = currentFriday.AddDays(1);
    }

    //FIND ALL THE FRIDAYS!
    int currentYear = startDate.Year;
    while (currentFriday.Year == currentYear)
    {
        results.Add(startDate.Day);
        currentFriday = currentFriday.AddDays(7);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Answer...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime begin = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now.AddDays(200);

        while (begin <= end)
        {
            if (begin.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                Console.WriteLine(begin.ToLongDateString());
            begin = begin.AddDays(1);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **CalendarPeriodCollector** of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void FindRemainigYearFridaysSample()
{
  // filter: only Fridays
  CalendarPeriodCollectorFilter filter = new CalendarPeriodCollectorFilter();
  filter.WeekDays.Add( DayOfWeek.Friday );

  // the collecting period
  CalendarTimeRange collectPeriod = new CalendarTimeRange( DateTime.Now, new Year().End.Date );

  // collect all Fridays
  CalendarPeriodCollector collector = new CalendarPeriodCollector( filter, collectPeriod );
  collector.CollectDays();

  // show the results
  foreach ( ITimePeriod period in collector.Periods )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Friday: " + period );
  }
} // FindRemainigYearFridaysSample
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm expert in vb.net .. but there is no different ..

I wrote the code below in `page_load` of a `asp.net` web form ...

1. make an `asp.net` application
2. add a web form to it
3. write the code below in `page_load`

   ```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
       Dim gc As New System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar
       Dim d As New DateTime(gc.GetYear(DateTime.Now), 1, 1)
       Dim i As Int16 = 1
       While i <= gc.GetDaysInYear(gc.GetYear(DateTime.Now))
           If gc.GetDayOfWeek(d) = DayOfWeek.Friday Then
               Response.Write(d & "<br />")
               d = gc.AddDays(d, 7)
               i += 7
           Else
               d = gc.AddDays(d, 1)
               i += 1
           End If
       End While
   End Sub
   ```