# How to find all certain days of week in the given year?

Tags: c#, datetime

My task is to find all Friday, 13 in a year that user inputs.

Can somebody explain how to do it? (I'm a beginner in c#)

Comment: You're getting down votes because you should show some effort to answer the question yourself, maybe show some code that you have tried and ask for help on how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int year = 2015;
for(int m=1; m<=12; m++)
{
    var dt = new DateTime(year, m, 13);
    if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)           
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortDateString());          
}
```

Comment: ty, it seems so simple, but its damn smart, oh well, one day i will be able to write smart code too =)!

Comment: @DraganItmSmoljan, skills come with practice. if my answer helped, mark it as Accepted, please

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get these dates in [Gregorian Calender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), you can use a combination of a loop, [`DateTime` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`DayOfWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration like;

```
int year = 2015;
for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
{
     if(new DateTime(year, i, 13).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
       Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(year, i, 13));
}
```

For `2015`, result will be;

```
13.02.2015 00:00:00
13.03.2015 00:00:00
13.11.2015 00:00:00
```

If you want to number of months, you can use [`.Month` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the result like;

```
Console.WriteLine((new DateTime(year, i, 13)).Month);
```

If you want to get your month names based on your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can use custom [`MMMM` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx?#MMMM_Specifier) like;

```
Console.WriteLine((new DateTime(year, i, 13)).ToString("MMMM"));
```

Also you can use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) like;

```
List<int> monthList = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).
            Where(d => new DateTime(2015, d, 13).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday).
            ToList(); // {2, 3, 11}
```

or

```
List<string> monthList = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).
               Where(d => new DateTime(2015, d, 13).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday).
               Select(m => new DateTime(2015, m, 13).ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).
               ToList(); // {February, March, November}
```

Comment: I think displaying just the month would be enough since it asks for specificly friday 13th of a specific year. so only the year could be diffrent anyway. But I must say nice and easy to read code.

Comment: @maam27 Sure, I added it as well.

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the dates you may use *Linq*:

```
   var dates = Enumerable
     .Range(1, 12) // All months
     .Select(month => new DateTime(2015, month, 13)) 
     .Where(date => date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday);
```

To print out them

```
   Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, dates));
```

Comment: You can improve efficiency by creating only 12 dates to examine rather than 365 (actually 366 here)

Answer (score 0):

Try to inspire by the code showed in that thread:
[Finding every friday from start date till the end of the year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128863/finding-every-friday-from-start-date-till-the-end-of-the-year)

(of course you will have to check if selected Friday is 13th)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this using linq.

```
var year = 2015;
        var months = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };

        var unluckyDays = months.Select(m => new DateTime(year, m, 13)).Where(dt => dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday);
```

The first Select statement projects the list of integers into a list of datetimes representing the 13th of each month in the year specified.

Then simply filter this list to those where the day of the week is Friday.

Comment: You could replace `months` with `Enumerable.Range(1,12)`

Answer (score 0):

DateTime objects have a property on them called DayOfWeek. You can utilize this to help you figure out if a date supplied returns a DayOfWeek Value of Friday: see below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++)
        {
            DateTime date = new DateTime(2015, i, 13);
            if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                Console.WriteLine(date.ToShortDateString());
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite simple

```
int year = 2014;
DateTime day = new DateTime(2014,1,1);
while (day.Year == year)
{
    if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday && day.Day == 13)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(day);
    }
    day = day.AddDays(1);
}
```

You init a DateTime variable in the start of the year 
Then you loop over each day of the year in this code I printed it

You can find more info of the DateTime class here

[DateTime Day of the week](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[DateTime referenc in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This prints all the Fridays in a year, not just the Fridays that fall on the 13th of a month.